# Java - read String and int: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I try to read an int and after it a string, in this way:

```
String wantA = "";
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter A");
wantA = in.nextLine();
in.close();   
// some code
int want = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Save? Press 1 for yes, or 0 for no");
want = in.nextInt();
in.close();
```

after it prints

> `Save? Press 1 for yes, or 0 for no`

then I get

> `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

How can I fix it?

Comment: @deporter What points are missing? And why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `in.close();` - it is killing the input stream (which never gets reopened).

Instead just keep using the same `Scanner`.
Change your code to this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter A");
String wantA = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Save? Press 1 for yes, or 0 for no");
int want = in.nextInt();
```